# Show model error on view without strongly binding asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

i have problem in showing model error.Model error is showing when i am using strongly binding the form. But when i am not using strongly data binding it is not showing model error.So how i can show the model error or validation **without** strongly binding and why it is not showing model error without strongly binding.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult productFilter()
{
    catName();
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult productFilter(productFilterModel filter)
{
    catName();
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //other operations here
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class productFilterModel
{
   [Required]
   public string catName { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int maxPrice { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int minPrice { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@model  RentalServices.Models.productFilterModel

// with strongly binding form and showing model error

<form action="/Product/productFilter" method="post">

    <label>Category</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.catName, ViewBag.catName as SelectList, "CHOOSE CATEGORY", new { @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessage("catName", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <label>Min Price</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.minPrice, new { @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessage("minPrice", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <label>Mxn Price</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.maxPrice, new { @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessage("maxPrice", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

// without strongly binding form and not showing model error

<form action="/Product/productFilter" method="post">

    <label>Category</label>
    <select name="catName">
    <option value="1">mobile</option>
    <option value="2">laptop</option>
    <option value="3">printer</option>
    </select>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("catName", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <label>Min Price</label>
    <input type= "number" name="minPrice" />
    @Html.ValidationMessage("minPrice", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <label>Max Price</label>
    <input type= "number" name="maxPrice" />
    @Html.ValidationMessage("maxPrice", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: you need to put manually validation in all control either you can go with jquery **validator** method in MVC

Comment: i am already using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and `jquery.validate.js` but not showing error without strongly binding form.

Comment: check [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-validationmessage) link .Hope it helps

Comment: You can use while button click check `$("form").valid()` if form return true then submit your form

Answer (score 0):

Model error is for the strongly typed,but if you do not want to use strongly typed view then you have to create custom validation .One of the way is that in controller you can check if the field is null or not,if it is null then you can use TempData to print the error message

Comment: i think it is lengthy process to check the every field . if i want to check validation with regex how to do that? if i have multiple validations on single attribute so i have to check every validation for every attribute so that,s not fair i think.